# Update two textarea content simultanously in AngularJs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to update the content of textarea 2 with that of 1 using angularjs.
This is my attempt

```
<textarea ng-model="messagetext" id="messageInput" ng-change="content=messagetext"></textarea>
<textarea value"{{content}}"ng-model="content" rows="2" placeholder="Share your thoughts via text and multimedia ..."></textarea>
```

my challenge is that the second textarea never gets updated.
please what could be wrong?

Comment: there is an '=' missing between value and content in the second textarea

Comment: set them to have the same `ng-model`

Comment: @Akis_Tfs OP said one direction. `ng-model` would be bi-directional.

Comment: You are right @Fresheyeball. Making both thesame model defeats the intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `value` as well as `ng-model` and those are in conflict.

https://jsfiddle.net/qqxrdtpt/

```
<textarea ng-model="messagetext" id="messageInput" ng-change="content=messagetext"></textarea>
<textarea ng-model="content" rows="2" placeholder="Share your thoughts via text and multimedia ..."></textarea>
```

Remove `value` and it works just fine.

Comment: @JnG The referenced Fiddle seems to work perfectly. What about the approach didn't work for you?

Comment: Forgot to hit ctrl+s